# How can I identify unused variables and attributes in attributes, recipes and templates?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

How can unused attributes be identified?

1. Cookbook attributes: If `attributes/default.rb` contains some attribute which is not used in cookbook recipes, `ruby -wc` and `knife cookbook test` obviously says OK.
2. Roles attributes: If `role-name.rb` role contains some attribute, which is not used in any cookbook recipe, `ruby -wc` obviously says OK.
3. Template calls in recipe: If `recipes/default.rb` recipe contains template call with variable which is not used in template file, `ruby -wc` and `knife cookbook test` obviously says OK.
4. Unused variables in recipe: If there is some unused variable in recipe, `ruby -wc` tells OK.

Answer (score 0):

There is a linting tool for chef cookbooks called [foodcritic](http://acrmp.github.io/foodcritic). While it does not cover all your requirements (only the 3rd one), it has also some other rules, that cookbooks are checked against. You may try to propose your checks there, or even implement them yourself :), using the existing Rule API.